# Typescript - How to make package users import dist folder as the package name?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package

I'm trying to write a package using typescript, this package contains some declarations that should be imported and used by user. The problem is I have a `src` and a `dist` folder generated from `src`. When I publish the package I can not import it as `@scope/package-name` instead of that I should import the definitions from `@scope/package-name/dist`. How can I import from the dist folder using the name of the package? `@scope/package-name`

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same problem.

Comment: You can try having a `.d.ts` file named `something` and write `export * from './dist/somthing'`

Comment: And where you wuld put such `d.ts` file?

Comment: In the root folder next to the `src`

Answer (score 0):

You should point to the dist folder in your package.json file.

**[Main](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#main)**

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs it, and then does `import * from "foo"`, then your main module's exports object will be returned.

This should be a module relative to the root of your package folder.

For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and often not much else.

If main is not set it defaults to index.js in the packages root folder.

**In your case, include this in your package.json:**

`"main": "dist/index.js",`